# User Interface Compiler (Uic) qt3 vs qt4/5, impl argument equivalence

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4, qt3

I would like to know what happened to the -impl argument in qt4/5 that was available in qt3?

- qt3 : https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/uic.html
- qt5 : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html

This argument is gone from qt4 and 5 and I am wondering if there is an equivalence or it is just obsolete and not needed anymore in 4/5?

thx

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.qt.io/topic/117400/user-interface-compiler-uic-qt3-vs-qt4-5-impl-argument-equivalence/2

I guess it's not needed anymore. If I understood the Qt3 docs correctly, it was there to set a custom header file or name.
Now, the class and uic will set up the header automatically.
(mainWindow.h mainWindow.ui -> ui_mainWindow.h)